# Smaller, well-behaved subsets of the function space of a successor cardinal

Tags: set-theory

Suppose $\kappa$ is an infinite cardinal. I'm trying to show that there's a subset $X\subseteq \kappa^{+^{\kappa^+}}$ with $|X|=\kappa$ and for any $\alpha<\beta$, we have $f\in X$ with $f(\alpha)=\beta$ or $f(\beta)=\alpha$. I find this result very counterintuitive, and so don't know how to begin proving it. Any help would be appreciated (the hint my professor gave me was to use the axiom of choice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $\beta\in\kappa^+$ choose a surjection $h_\beta:\kappa\to\beta+1.$

For each $\xi\in\kappa$ define $f_\xi:\kappa^+\to\kappa^+$ by setting $f_\xi(\beta)=h_\beta(\xi).$

If $\alpha\le\beta\in\kappa^+$ then there exists $\xi\in\kappa$ such that $f_\xi(\beta)=h_\beta(\xi)=\alpha.$

Let $X=\{f_\xi:\xi\in\kappa\}.$